# How do I write this code as recursion?

Tags: java, recursion

I made this code in Java for counting the number of chars in an array.  However, I didn't use recursion.  Can someone rewrite this as recursion, please?
How can I convert `for loop` and `count++`?

```
public int count(char[] arr, char ch) {  
    if (arr == null) {  
        return -1;  
    }  
    int count = 0;  
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {        
        if (arr[i] == ch) {  
            count++;  
        }  
    }  
    return count;  
}
```

Comment: @kkaosninja he isn´t asking about a currently happening recursion, he wants us to rewrite this into recursion as far as i got it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your attempt and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.  I see no attempt here to write this as recursion.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of iterating trough a loop, for recursion the function you write has to call itself (hence you need a third parameter, which is the current position you have in the array).

You simply start at index 0, returning 0 if the current char is not your char, or 1 if it is. Then, you have to do the same for the rest of the array. When you reach the end (`currIndex == arr.length`), you return 0 as a starting value for the summation.

```
  public static void main (final String[] args) {
    char[] foo = {'f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r'};
    System.out.println (count (foo, 'o')); // 2
    System.out.println (countRecursive (foo, 'o')); // 2
  }

  public static int countRecursive (final char[] arr,
                                    final char ch) {
    return countRecursive (arr, ch, 0);
  }

  public static int countRecursive (final char[] arr,
                                    final char ch,
                                    final int currIndex) {
    if (currIndex == arr.length) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return (arr[currIndex] == ch ? 1 : 0) + countRecursive (arr, ch, currIndex + 1);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int count(char[] arr, char ch) {  
    if (arr == null  || arr.length ==0) {  
        return 0;  
    }
    char[] oneSmallerArr = new char[arr.length-1];
    System.arraycopy(arr, 1, oneSmallerArr, 0, oneSmallerArr.length);
    return (arr[0] == ch ? 1 : 0) + count(oneSmallerArr, ch);
}
```

Comment: Are you really suggesting an algorithm with complexity O(n^2) for such task?

Comment: It may be inefficient, but it has the shape it would have in an FP language. There would be a cons-list of chars instead of the array.